# Using UBINIZE to create a UBI image, but the resulting image has different properties from the original file

Tags: linux, filesystems, ubifs

My goal is to gain root access to a UBI filesystem. I used [ubi_reader](https://github.com/onekey-sec/ubi_reader) with the command  to get the description for my file (rootfs.ubi). Here is the command I used:

**ubireader_display_info rootfs.ubi**

[image: Original UBI file description]

Next, I extracted the files from rootfs.ubi to my Linux subsystem (I use WSL) and modified the necessary files. In order to repack the files together in .ubi format, I used [ubinize](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/ubinize.8.html) and this config file:

[image: cfg.ini]

Then I ran the command

"**ubinize -o rootfs.ubi -p 256KiB -m 2048 -s 2048 cfg.ini**"

This packs the files together into a UBI file. The problem is, this file description does not match the original file description. The total block count is way higher in the original file. Look: [image: New UBI file description]

I tried modifying the ubinize code for a while, but I am not getting the exact numbers as the original file.

In summary, I don't know how to get my modified UBI file to be the same as the original and I would appreciate any help! Thank you very much.